# Получение цвета данного пикселя

Tags: java, swing

Как при наведении мышки узнать соответствует ли пиксель данному цвету или нет?

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Класс Robot содержит метод getPixelColor(int x, int y), который вернет цвет пикселя в указанной координате.

Получить координаты указателя можно через методы MouseInfo

```
int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
Robot robot = new Robot();
Color color = robot.getPixelColor(x,y);
```